# How to drop index columns from the rest of data frame columns after group by?

Tags: pandas, group-by

Consider a table like

```
A  B   C  D
......
```

I do groupby like:

```
    gcol = ['A','B']
    gdf = df.groupby(gcol, as_index=True).agg(_agg) #.reset_index(drop=True)
    table = gdf.to_latex(index=True, escape=True)
```

So, I just want to see A and B as index column in the latex table, but they are present in the rest of columns.

What I have:

```
A  B  A B C  D
......
```

What I like:

```
A  B   C  D
......
```

Answer (score 2):

IIUC, you just need to select the wanted columns:

```
gcol = ['A','B']

cols = df.columns.difference(gcol)
gdf = df.groupby(gcol, as_index=True)[cols].agg(_agg)

table = gdf.to_latex(index=True, escape=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution as following:

```
gdf = df.groupby(gcol, as_index=False).agg(_agg)

# Convert the 'gcol' columns to index and use inplace=True
gdf.set_index(gcol, inplace=True)
```